# Single Table Inheritance & ActiveRecord Associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, inheritance, activerecord, abstract-class, single-table-inheritance

I'm attempting to have a parent model that other models inherit from, and a secondary class that has associations with the children from the first model.  Here's what I have so far...

I used the first command to create the parent model.

```
rails g model Person name:string age:integer height:float
```

I then set up `Person` as the parent class, and two children class which inherit from it as seen below.

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
    self.abstract_class = true
end

class Driver < Person
    self.table_name = "Driver"
    belongs_to :vehicle
end

class Passenger < Person
    self.table_name = "Passenger"
    belongs_to :vehicle
end
```

I also set up a `Vehicle` class to use in an association with the `Driver` and `Passenger` children classes.

```
rails g model Vehicle color:string capacity:integer

class Vehicle < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :driver
    has_many :passengers
end
```

However, if I use the rails console and attempt to create a new instance Driver or Passenger, using `Driver.new` or `Passenger.new`, I encounter an PostgreSQL error.

For reasons which I cannot figure out, Rails is writing SQL statements to query on a `Driver` or `Passenger` table.  However, it is my understanding that only one `Person` table is made and has a `type` attribute that is used for queries.

If anyone can offer some guidance here, I'd be very appreciative.

Thanks

Comment: Can you show us the postgres error.

Comment: I tried running `$ vehicle = Vehicle.new` and `$ vehicle.driver = Driver.create`.  I've posted the [error on pastebin](http://pastebin.com/LbPi8Urv)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it seems you're trying to use the common table `persons` for both `Driver` and `Passenger`, you don't need the `abstract_class` declaration, or the `table_name` declarations in either of the sub classes.  Per the rails documentation, these options would be used when you want classes to inherit behavior from their parent, without the parent itself having a table.

The snippet below should work fine.

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class Driver < Person
    belongs_to :vehicle
end

class Passenger < Person
    belongs_to :vehicle
end
```

Comment: Thank you, Ben!  That's definitely helping.  I'm still encountering an issue if I attempt to use `Vehicle.driver` to try to add an association though.  Any ideas?

Comment: `$ vehicle = Vehicle.new` and `$ vehicle.driver = Driver.new` lead to the error: `ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError: can't write unknown attribute 'vehicle_id'`

Comment: I also tried `$ vehicle.driver.build` before the previous commands as well, it produced the error: `NoMethodError: undefined method `build' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: My best guess is that the `persons` table is lacking a `vehicle_id` column.

Comment: Oops.  Stupid mistake on my part.  Thanks for your help!  Added `add_column :people, :vehicle, index: true` and it seems to be helping out here.